# Zend Date Weirdness - Missing Configuration?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-date

I'm getting odd output from the `getDate()` function.  It's supposed to return a date without the time parts, but I am getting time parts.  Am I missing some configuration option that would correct this?

Sample Code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = new Zend_Date(array(
    'year' => 2010,
    'month' => 3,
    'day' => 29,
));
echo $date->getIso() . PHP_EOL;
echo $date->getDate()->getIso() . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
2010-03-29T00:00:00-04:00
2010-03-29T23:00:00-04:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to my question, but this is my workaround.  I have extended the `Zend_Date` class as follows:

```
class My_Date extends Zend_Date
{
    public static function now($locale = null)
    {
        return new My_Date(time(), self::TIMESTAMP, $locale);
    }

    /**
     * set to the first second of current day
     */
    public function setDayStart()
    {
        return $this->setHour(0)->setMinute(0)->setSecond(0);
    }

    /**
     * get the first second of current day
     */
    public function getDayStart()
    {
        $clone = clone $this;
        return $clone->setDayStart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend Date's `getDate` method is easy to misunderstand.  Its output is really not to be used except to compare with another `getDate` output, and only to see how two dates compare vis-a-vis their calendar date.  Consider it a "calendar date hash function".

Example (good): do these two dates fall on the same calendar date?

```
$date1->getDate()->equals($date2->getDate()); // works as expected
```

Example (bad):

```
echo $date1->getDate(); // is meaningless
echo $date1->getCalendarDateHash(); // just as this would be
$date1 = $date1->getDate(); // and don't store this meaningless value
```

If you're looking for it to set the time part to 00:00:00, look elsewhere.

Comment: Good to know why it's behaving that way. It should be documented more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, try this:

```
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::DATE_FULL);
```

Comment: That does work for output, but it doesn't return a `Zend_Date` object stripped of the time parts.

Comment: from the manual: The getDate() method parses strings containing dates in localized formats. The results are returned in a structured array, with well-defined keys for each part of the date.

Comment: You're referring to `Zend_Locale_Format::getDate()`.  The `getDate()` function in `Zend_Date` is documented like this: `Returns a clone of $this, with the time part set to 00:00:00.`

Answer (score 0):

For more see

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.list

Comment: My question is not about the date constants

Comment: I am on 1.10.5.  If you look at the last comment on that bug, another person is seeing the same behavior as me.  I just wasn't sure if we both were doing the same thing wrong since there was no reply to that comment.

Comment: Same version as you, same problem here. The only way around it is to use the set method, or revert back to the 0 timezone. Set is probably better. I'd make my own class and extend Zend_Date, that way you won't have to keep remembering to reset it

Edit.. just seen you already have